# Creating branches from git-worktree given an absolute path

Tags: git, git-worktree

When using a `git worktree add /tmp/foo` without specifying a branch, a new branch 'foo' will be created. This is documented on the man pages for git-[worktree](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree):

> COMMANDS
> `add <path> [<branch>]`
> Create `<path>` and checkout `<branch>` into it. [...].
> If `<branch>` is omitted and neither -b nor -B nor --detached used, then, as a convenience, a new branch based at HEAD is created automatically, **as if -b $(basename ) was specified**.

Is there a way to modify this to create branches under the typical branch naming pattern `feature/<ticket>-<description>` ? Were I to call `git worktree add /tmp/feature/<ticket>-foo`, the branch would be called `<ticket>-foo` with the `feature/` missing.

I know that when I use a relative path it works. Then a path and a branch is created from where I called the command. But that would require that I had to work with a bare repository. (Otherwise nested worktrees are problematic.)

The best I could make to work was using `git worktree add ../feature/<ticket>-foo`. Then the branch will be `feature/<ticket>-foo` and the path will be `../feature/<ticket>-foo`. But being able to specify an absolute directory would be very useful.

Comment: Why not simply explicitly name both the work-tree *and* the branch, so that the path does not imply the branch? If you build this into a script that simply passes the same name as the branch and as the final component(s) of the path, the explicit strings you give will match the way you want.

Comment: @torek writing a script is a good idea. Manually specifying both is too much work.